# Does MSDN use wrong terminology when referring to events and their event handlers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I’ve noticed that on several occasions that MSDN uses “wrong” terminology when referring to events and their event handlers. For example:

> The ProfileAutoSaving event is raised at the end of page execution if the ProfileManager.AutomaticSaveEnabled property is true. You can access the ProfileAutoSaving event of the ProfileModule class in the Global.asax file for your ASP.NET application using the Profile_ProfileAutoSaving global event

Why does the above quote describe Profile_ProfileAutoSaving as *global event*, when to my knowledge it is actually an event handler subscribed to ProfileAutoSaving event?!

thanx

Comment: This belongs on MSDN's feedback, not StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. But question is not so much why MSDN uses the wrong terminology, but whether my assumption that  Profile_ProfileAutoSaving is an event handler is indeed correct.

Comment: A link to the MSDN page in question might be helpful.

Comment: Here is the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilemodule.profileautosaving(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a global event because it's located in the Global.asax file? What's wrong about that?

**Edit:** I'm not sure what your distinction is between a "global event" and an "event handler." Those aren't mutually exclusive descriptions. Essentially, this is a global event handler.

Comment: So Profile_ProfileAutoSaving is global event and not an event handler?

Answer (score 2):

The use of this terminology is specific to Global.asax, which has backwards compatibility features to make it similar to Global.asa from Classic ASP. `Profile_ProfileAutoSaving` is a global event in exactly the same way that `Application_Error` is a global event.